# Sumtable (vtable) as object

Tags: r, vtable

I created a sumtable with a package (vtable)

`Object<-st(df)`

The Object is NULL and the table is only in the Viewer or in html link. I would like to combine few tables and plots into one HTML, but can’t figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `vtable::sumtable()` to return a data frame for further manipulation, use the `out = 'return'` option of `sumtable()` to get the result back in `data.frame` form. This may drop some formatting not consistent with `data.frame`s, like multi-column cells.

```r
library(vtable)
my_sumtable <- sumtable(mtcars, out = 'return')
my_sumtable
```